Is there a default build-in function or template which returns zero?
Sometimes I need a function or template which returns zero like in the example below (artificial, of course, for sake of simplicity).
I am fine to write everywhere []() { return 0.0f; }, but taking into account that we have many predefined function objects for similar often used things like std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity, etc., don't we have something like std::zero<T> which is recommended to use in such cases?
(I am not asking to introduce it, I just want to double check that I don't miss recommended to use thing which could make code nicer).
#include <vector>

void add(std::vector<float>& v, std::size_t sz, auto gen) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        v.emplace_back(gen());
    }
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<float> v;
    add(v, 5, []() { return 0.0f; });
}


Terminology note: "predicate" implies that the result is supposed to be interpreted as a truth value. You're not interpreting the result as a truth value, so "predicate" is the wrong word to use here.

I don't believe the standard provides one.  You can make your own: template <typename T> T zero() { return T{}; }.

defaulted might be a better name then.

If you want to write []() { return 0.0f;} you don't need a lambda you can just have a free function auto return_zero_f { return 0.0f; } and use that instead (more readable too).

Or create an overload for add without the 3rd parameter

"we have many predefined function objects for similar often used things like std::less," -- Or not so similar. cppreference.com lists std::less as an operator function object. Zero is a constant, not an operator, so there is not much similarity here. (I'd also dispute "often used" as a description of a function that always returns zero, but I recognize mileage may vary.)

@Eljay "template <typename T> T zero() { return T{}; }" -- For more versatility, the value could be a template parameter with a suitable default: template <typename T, T value = T{}> T constant() { return value; }

@user2357112, thank you for catching this. The question has been updated.

@JaMiT, agreed. Replaced with std::numeric_limits<T>::infinitywhich is much closer. The idea was that we have predefined things which could be easily defined by ourselves, but we have them, since they often used and often used in STL itself. The 'std::less' sprung to mind just because it is used more often.

std::integral_constant<int, 0> f0; but it is only available for integral types and explicitly needs the 0 value or default initializer.

@Red.Wave, thank you. It is a funny situation when both question and answer are totally correct, and, yet, the answer doesn't help. I mean that your answer helps in terms of the question and it totally covers it, but I guess we both will agree that in real code we won't use this to "make code nicer" (from original question). I would say, for this purpose it won't pass Occam's razor. Again, thank you, I get the point. Real question would be where std::integral_constant is really needed; I will look std later for examples.

Zero of what? Arithmetic types? Integral types? Any class that wraps an integral type/types? This last one is significant since the role of zero as "identity" value can be filled by something other than integer zero. Anyway, if you're asking about more than arithmetic types, then it can't exist for that reason; if only those, then it could but doesn't, presumably due to lack of demand.

@DamirTenishev funny thing is most of - now standard - features started as syntax abuse. I don't know what you are trying to do; if functional programming you seek, I can give a simple lambda: auto constexpr value_fn=[](auto v){ return bind_front(std::identity<>{}, std::forward<decltype(v)>(v) ); }; given an arbitrary value of a movable/copyable type, value_fn returns a function fixed at input value.
